# Show that every even number is in $A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

Suppose $A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$

(1) $0\in A$

(2) for all $m\in \mathbb{Z},$ if $m\in A$ then $m-2,m+2\in A$

Show that every  even number is in $A$

my attmept: as $0=2\times 0$ and if $m $ is positive even number and $m\in A$ then $m+2=2x+2 \in A$ as given

$m $ is negative  even number and $m\in A$ then $m-2=-2x-2 \in A$ as given

Show that every  even number is in $A$

Comment: Choose the smallest positive even number that’s not in $A$.  Prove there must be a smaller one.  Choose the largest negative even number that’s not in $A$.  Prove that there must be a larger one.  This pair of contradictions shows that the set of even numbers not in $A$ must be empty.

Comment: Using MI twice proves the statement.

Comment: You appear to trying to prove it by induction, but you have phrased it so poorly that only long experience with badly written proofs allows me to determine this. A proof is an argument that is supposed to convince your reader of the truth of the claim. Read this as if you had never seen it before. Would you be convinced by it? Would you even be able to figure out what it was saying? (If you answered either of those "yes", then you are fooling yourself.) Be clear in what you say. Introduce it carefully. Do not expect your readers to fill in your gaps. Define variables ($x$) before you use them.

Answer (score 1):

First, we show that every positive even number $2n$ belongs to $A$ by induction on $n$.

- The induction basis holds since $2 \cdot 1 = 0 + 2 \in A$.
- For the induction step, assume that $2k \in A$; we have $2(k+1) = 2k + 2 \in A$.

This completes the induction, proving that every positive even number belongs to $A$.

Similarly, it can be proved that every negative even number belongs to $A$, and then we are done.